# Error splicing file while copying even with small files

Tags: shared-folders, vmware-player, copy-and-paste

I am using VMware and Ubuntu 20.04 as guest, win7 as host. While trying to copy files to shared folder I am getting "Error splicing file:input/output error"

It used to work, but I made copy of virtual machine and now it works only with small text files, but when size is about 1 MB and more, error appears.

From windows I can read and write to shared folder with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your VMware Workstation version and consider an update. The official support for Ubuntu 20.04 starts with version 15.5.5, see [VMware Workstation 15.5.5 Player Release Notes](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player/15.5/rn/VMware-Workstation-1555-Player-Release-Notes.html).

I had the exact same problem when I copied a 20.04-VM from a colleague (interestingly enough he built it with Workstation 12.x and it ran fine for him). I updated from Workstation 15.5.1 to 15.5.6. Then it worked.

Comment: Thanks for help, new version solved it.